# Debugging with gdb showing segfault in question marks function "?? ()"

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to debug a segfault with gdb, but it shows error occurs in "?? ()" step which I can't figure out the meaning. Anyone can give a hint what that means?

The relevant backtrace is posted below.

```
(gdb) run
> (list-partition gt3 (quote (1 2 3 4 5)))

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7d900ac in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 

(gdb) bt 10
#0  0xb7d900ac in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb7d92dec in malloc () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7f8d627 in operator new(unsigned int) ()    from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0xb7f727d4 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0xb7f74a48 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) ()    from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0xb7f74bb6 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) ()    from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x080527fa in SymbolCell::get_symbol (this=0x80641e0) at SymbolCell.cpp:63
#7  0x080524c2 in SymbolCell::get_value (this=0x80641e0) at SymbolCell.cpp:88
#8  0x08053c20 in ConsCell::get_value (this=0x8064190) at ConsCell.cpp:195
#9  0x0804f287 in eval_pure (c=0x8064190) at eval_util.cpp:683 (More stack frames follow...)
```

Another thing worth noticing is that the program actually runs a few seconds before generate this bug, which is quite abnormal in the context of the behavior of the program.

Appreciate any suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're looking too low level. Go up a few frames and you'll see the problem begins in `SymbolCell::get_symbol`. Focus on that because `malloc` and your OS are _not_ the culprits!

Comment: Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441017/how-can-malloc-cause-a-sigsegv Probably your heap is corrupted. For the ??, it just means that no debug information is linked to lookup the name of the function at the address 0xb7d900ac

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks! It is definitely wrong with my program, not the library I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`??()` means that gdb can't find symbolic information.  This is not necessary for your problem because the stack is already deep in the library code and string/new/malloc are well tested.  Start at frame 6 in `SymbolCell::get_symbol` to look for problems.

*edit*: I just noticed that you are actually running lisp-code, so you might have run into some issues with the lisp environment or more likely are running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is actually a mini-Scheme interpreter I write. Could you elaborate on the possible issues with the environment that causing running out of memory? It can be a possible cause of the bug since the `SymbolCell::get_symbol` just returns `std::string(char* symbol_m)` (a data member) which normally works well.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe some kind of endless loop, that normally eats up your stack, but crashing in malloc hints at possible out of memory situations.  I was thinking that you could contact the lisp guys, but since it is your interpreter, you probably will need to do some digging.  Anyway, as Lightness and me suggest, the problem is likely not in the c/c++ library.

Comment: memory allocation failure rarely, but not never, segfaults.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: also not when a lot of small allocations are done exhausting some resources used by malloc?  I suggested that based on the debug stack, because mostly crashes are seen when freeing.  Having said that, it could also be the result of a previous corruption causing the crash in an unexpected place.

Comment: @stefaanv that would be my guess